# Silverlight + Facebook DTK API -> SecurityException ONLY on Mac and Firefox

Tags: silverlight, exception, facebook

I have a SilverLight application which throws a security exception when running on FireFox for Macs. The exact same application works fine on Windows (Internet Explorer, FireFox, Chrome, Opera) and on Safari for Macs.

I am using the Facebook Developer Toolkit available on Codeplex.

The exception is thrown when the user launches the App. At that time I use the SilverLight Facebook API to run some queries using:

```
facebookAPI.Fql.MultiqueryAsync(queries, QueryAppUsersCompleted, dispatcher);
```

In my callback function `QueryAppUsersCompleted`, the FacebookException does not evaluate to null, and its `innerException` property has a SecurityException in it.

Any help would be tremendously appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else runs into this, this has now been fixed with the latest Facebook Developer Toolkit.